# Tikz: Line trajectory joining two nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, line

I am drawing a line linking two nodes. I do not understand the strange behavior of the line. Why the line pass the arrival point and then back to the final point?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]  

    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,6);
    \coordinate (C) at (3,0);     
    \coordinate (D) at (3,6);
    \coordinate (E) at (5.5,0);         
    \coordinate (F) at (5.5,6);  
    \coordinate (G) at (10,0);          
    \coordinate (H) at (10,6);          

    \draw [name path=A--B] (A) -- (B);
    \draw [name path=B--H] (B) -- (H);
    \draw [name path=H--G] (H) -- (G);
    \draw [name path=C--D] (G) -- (A);
    \draw [dashed,name path=C--D] (C) -- (D); 
    \draw [dashed,name path=E--F] (E) -- (F);

    \path [name path=A--P1] (A) -- (25:10);             
    \draw [name intersections={of=E--F and A--P1, by=P1}];                          
    \node [draw,inner sep=5pt,anchor=east](p1) at (P1)  {};

    \path [name path=A--P2] (A) -- (37:10);
    \draw [name intersections={of=C--D and A--P2, by=P2}] (A) -- (G);                    
    \path [name path=P2--P3] (P2) -- ++(12:10);
    \path [name intersections={of=H--G and P2--P3, by=P3}];  
    \node [draw,anchor=west,inner sep=5pt](p3) at (P3)  {};
    \draw (p1.east) to [out=25,in=12] (p3.west);

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]  

    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (0,6);
    \coordinate (C) at (3,0);     
    \coordinate (D) at (3,6);
    \coordinate (E) at (5.5,0);         
    \coordinate (F) at (5.5,6);  
    \coordinate (G) at (10,0);          
    \coordinate (H) at (10,6);          

    \draw [name path=A--B] (A) -- (B);
    \draw [name path=B--H] (B) -- (H);
    \draw [name path=H--G] (H) -- (G);
    \draw [name path=C--D] (G) -- (A);
    \draw [dashed,name path=C--D] (C) -- (D); 
    \draw [dashed,name path=E--F] (E) -- (F);

    \path [name path=A--P1] (A) -- (25:10); % a bit longer, so that there is an intersection                
    \draw [name intersections={of=E--F and A--P1, by=P1}] (A) -- (P1);                          
    \node [inner sep=0pt,text width=0,anchor=east](p1) at (P1)  {};

    \path [name path=A--P2] (A) -- (37:10); % a bit longer, so that there is an intersection   
    \draw [name intersections={of=C--D and A--P2, by=P2}] (A) -- (G);  
    \draw [name path=P1--P2] (P1) -- (P2); 
    \draw [dashed,blue] (P2) -- ++(17:8);                         
    \path [name path=P2--P3] (P2) -- ++(17:10); % a bit longer, so that there is an intersection
    \path [name intersections={of=H--G and P2--P3, by=P3}];  
    \node [,text width=0,anchor=west,inner sep=0pt](p3) at (P3)  {};
    \draw (p1.east) to [out=25,in=17] (p3.west);   

\end{tikzpicture}      
\end{document}
```

Final image:
[image]

Comment: Did you try changing the value of `in=` ?  It will probably look better with `in=180`.

Comment: The `in` angle, as mentioned by @Thruston, is the reason. Ti*k*Z gives you what you are asking for.

Comment: @Thruston, I need to define exactly the in and out angle. Reason: the line linking the nodes was the form that I found to make a curve beginning at one point and ends at another point (with specified angles). So, this curve must be tangent to a straight line (dashed blue line).  
Schrödinger's cat, yes, you are correct. However, I expected that Tikz to be smart enough to build the most simple trajectory. In the edited post, we can see that the arrival angle is the same as the dashed blue line. But, I would like that Tiks does not make last twist.

Comment: I really think you want `\draw (p1.east) to [out=25,in=17+180] (p3.west);`. Note the `+180`.